# Same quartz job running twice because of two server instances

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have this problem: my app has a quartz scheduler to run a task each X minutes. This app is deployed in two server instances, so each instance is executing the task at the same time. I want to execute only one task at the same time.

We have configured Quartz with Spring and our application server is WAS.

Which options do you suggest?

Comment: Wouldn't disable Quartz on one deploy configuration serve your purpose?

Comment: @EvertonAgner that's definitely bad solution. If node with quartz enabled will fail - other node's app will left with no quartz at all.

Comment: Okay okay, just asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could setup quartz cluster with JDBC job store - then every job fire will be executed by only one cluster node. You can find more information on that topic in quartz [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)

Comment: I am facing same situation, i am using plsql can u tell me solution